# Magento 2.1 - insert block before product title on Luma

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

I have a **custom module** that I'd like to **insert a block** into product page *before* the product name using Magento Luma theme.
I added the following layout xml file into Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\CustomBlock" name="product.info.custom_block" template="Vendor_Module::block.phtml" before="page.main.title" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

However, the custom block appears at the end of product.info.main not before the product name.
What I found is that luma is actually moving the page.main.title in own layout update vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

I believe my update is not working because Magento is first parsing the layout updates from modules, and then from themes. So when my block is inserted there's no `page.main.title` to insert before, so it ends up at the end, and then Magento parses updates from theme inserting title in `product.info.main`

Is there a way of ensuring that my block shows in the correct place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing just one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                   
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>                                              
       <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">                                                                                                                            
           <block class="Goivvy\Custom\Block\Product\View\CustomBlock" name="product.info.custom_block" template="Goivvy_Custom::block.phtml" before="-" />
       </referenceContainer>                           
       <!-- add this line below  -->   
       <move element="product.info.custom_block" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title" />
   </body>                                             
</page>
```

Comment: Working Great till now